# Awk command for summing 2 patterns in pairs from a text file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a repetition starting at row zzz in a text file.

```
zzz ***Wed Aug 16 06:00:30 UTC 2017
MemTotal:       195702024 kB
MemFree:         1323524 kB
..
Cached:         58020288 kB
..other rows
zzz ***Wed Aug 16 06:01:00 UTC 2017
MemTotal:       195702024 kB
MemFree:         1379588 kB
..other rows
Cached:         58001952 kB
..other rows
```

I want to sum up the values of **MemFree:** and **Cached:** for each repetition.
There are 3 columns on such lines. KB being the third column.

For eg:

```
MemFree:         1323524 kB + Cached:         58020288 kB = 59343812 
MemFree:         1379588 kB + Cached:         58001952 kB = 59381540
```

Want an output like:

```
Total Available Memory = 59343812
Total Available Memory = 59381540
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not clear what “row zzz” has to do with the question. 
Are there other occurrences of “MemFree:” and “Cached:” before row zzz
that you want ignored? 
But here is a simple solution
to capture the value from the second column of a “MemFree:” line, save it,
and add it to the value from the next “Cached:” line:

```
awk '
    $1 == "MemFree:" { free = $2 }
    $1 == "Cached:"  { print "Total Available Memory =", free+$2 }
    '
```